# C Language Program Compiled Will it use multicore cpu?

Tags: c

Platform: Windows XP
Processor : Dual Core

I have a program written in C Language which is compiled and its exe is formed.
My question is that will the program use both the Cores (since my machine is dual core) or I have to make my program multithreaded in order to do it ?

Comment: How exactly do you expect a single thread to run simultaneously on 2 cores?

Comment: Generally speaking you have to make your program multi-threaded in order to use more than one core.  If, however, you are using a library that makes use of multi-threading, then you may not have to worry about it.  You could improve your question by posting some code.

Comment: Part of the reason for having multi-core processors is so that the OS can do work even while your program is working ... your word processor can do a background save

Comment: Well, during it's execution, it *might* alternate between using cores if it gets migrated from one core's runqueue to another...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to implement a multithreaded program when you want to use multiple cores.

There are plenty of threading libraries out there. I'd recommend you have a look into [OpenMP website](http://openmp.org/), which is quite easy to integrate and use for parallization.

**EDIT:** a simple example:

Normally you can parallelize your `for` loops simply by adding:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for(...)
```

Of course, you have to link against OpenMP and compile with OpenMP support.

Comment: In C++ nothing is free except the rope. :)

Comment: In C, you pay for the rope too :-)

Answer (score 2):

short answer: you have to make your program multithreaded in order to make use of both cores.

Answer (score 0):

a single processor at a time can execute only one program.
so u need to create a thread and execcute both at the same time to use the dual core.